# Conflict file between nvidia-common and nvidia-installer-cleanup

Tags: dpkg

When I attempt to add or remove any package, I get an error message from apt-get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: nvidia-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Trying apt-get -f install:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nvidia-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/19.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 155 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 430130 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nvidia-common (from .../nvidia-common_1%3a0.2.44.2_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-common_1%3a0.2.44.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install', which is also in package nvidia-installer-cleanup 20131102+1~bpo70+1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-common_1%3a0.2.44.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Exit 100
```

Apparently two packages, nvidia-common and nvidia-installer-cleanup, share the same file, pre-install, which prevents nvidia-common from being installed, which prevents anything else from being installed. The truth is, I use a proprietary Radeon driver and do not even need NVidia.

P.S.
The output of dpkg -l | grep glx:

```
ii  glx-alternative-fglrx                         0.4.1~bpo70+1                                   allows the selection of FGLRX as GLX provider
ii  glx-alternative-mesa                          0.4.1~bpo70+1                                   allows the selection of MESA as GLX provider
ii  glx-diversions                                0.4.1~bpo70+1                                   prepare for using accelerated GLX implementations from GPU vendors
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx                               8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7                                free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386                          8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7                                free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
rc  libglitz-glx1                                 0.5.6-1build1                                   Glitz OpenGL library GLX backend
ii  libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni                          3.7.2-2                                         Standard Widget Toolkit for GTK+ GLX JNI library
ii  libxcb-glx0                                   1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2                                X C Binding, glx extension
ii  libxcb-glx0:i386                              1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2                                X C Binding, glx extension
```

The output of  apt-cache rdepends nvidia-common:

```
nvidia-common
Reverse Depends:
  jockey-common
  nvidia-common:i386
  ubuntu-desktop
  jockey-common
  nvidia-common:i386
  xubuntu-desktop
  ubuntustudio-desktop
  nvclock-qt
  nvclock-gtk
  nvclock
  mythbuntu-common
  lubuntu-core
  ubuntu-desktop
  kubuntu-desktop
  jockey-common
```

The output of apt-cache policy nvidia-common nvidia-installer-cleanup:

```
nvidia-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:0.2.44.2
  Version table:
     1:0.2.44.2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:0.2.44 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
nvidia-installer-cleanup:
  Installed: 20131102+1~bpo70+1
  Candidate: 20131102+1~bpo70+1
  Version table:
 *** 20131102+1~bpo70+1 0
        100 http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-backports/contrib amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: You could probably remove `nvidia-installer-cleanup`.

Comment: glx-diversions depends on it, and tons of other packages depend on glx-diversions. I am not sure how critical are they?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, not.

Comment: @DZinoviev: I would say it's not critical, and to proceed with caution.

Comment: @RegisteredUser this is not a duplicated.

Comment: Include also `apt-cache rdepends nvidia-common` and `apt-cache policy nvidia-common nvidia-installer-cleanup`.

Comment: Added both outputs.

Comment: Why are you using debian repository, just why

Comment: Good question. I don't know. Suppose I disable it. What would be my next step?

Comment: I updated my answer, just follow it.

Comment: Thanks, but glx-diversions still depends on nvidia-installer-cleanup and does not allow to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you installing Debian packages?! Don't do that! Remove the Debian repository using:

```
sudo sed -i '/debian/d' /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}
```

Then remove the `nvidia-installer-cleanup` package and make sure you don't have other Debian packages installed. Then run `sudo apt-get install -f` and hope it solves the issue.

---

Your `nvidia-common` package is trying to overwrite a file of `nvidia-installer-cleanup` as you have noticed. To get out of this situation you must give up installing `nvidia-common` or removing `nvidia-installer-cleanup`. I would use the later:

```
sudo dpkg --purge nvidia-installer-cleanup
```

and then run `sudo apt-get install -f` again. Since you also don't have NVidia cards I would just remove any and every nvidia package shown by `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`.

Comment: Braiam, glx-diversions depends on nvidia-installer-cleanup. I can remove either both or neither. And a lot of other glx packages depend on glx-diversions.

Comment: @DZinoviev include in your question the output of `dpkg -l | grep glx`

Comment: Added the output of dpkg -l | grep glx.